# Difference between ending a Python program with quit() or closing the window?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, exit

I would like to know if there is any difference in terms of cleaning the RAM and terminating the process, when you close the window in which your program is running, instead of using a quit() command in the script. I am using Windows, and executing the file directly without any editor and without using the console.

Comment: Can you check the memory stats before and after for each test??  What did you get?

Comment: The answer strongly depends on some factors, like how threads and subprocesses are run, how the close is implemented and the OS. In most usual cases it won't make a difference.

Comment: Don't use `quit()` in a script; that's meant for interactive use and depends on importing the site module at startup. Instead use `sys.exit([status])` or `raise SystemExit([status])`.